# Incorrect syntax near 'set Dynamic sql query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

/* When I execute this procedure in sql server it execute correctly but when I execute through coding i get this error "Incorrect syntax near set"
    Thanks in advance*/

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateCitationTrust]
@tblName varchar(50),
@updatedTableName varchar(50)

AS
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)
Declare @ParamDefinition AS NVarchar(2000) 
BEGIN
 --BEGIN TRANSACTION 


 set @sql='Update '+@updatedTableName+ ' set [Citation Flow]=m2.[Citation Flow],'+
    ' [Trust Flow]=m2.[Trust Flow]'+
    ' FROM '+ @updatedTableName+ ' m1 '+
    ' INNER JOIN  '+ @tblName+' m2'+
    ' on m1.[Linking Domain]=m2.[Item]'

 Set @ParamDefinition =      '@tblName varchar(50),
                @updatedTableName varchar(50)'



 Execute sp_Executesql     @sql, 
                @ParamDefinition, 
                @tblName,
                @updatedTableName


    If @@ERROR <> 0 GoTo ErrorHandler 
    Set NoCount OFF
    Return(0)

ErrorHandler:
    Return(@@ERROR)
END
```

Comment: are u passing parameters to your procedure correctly?

Comment: sqlCon.Open();
                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tmpTableName", strTempTable2);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@updatedTableName", updatedTableName);

Comment: check what exactly is being passed through strTempTable2 and updatedTableName by using debugger

Comment: through strTempTable2 and updatedTableName i am passing dynamically generated  table name which i took in string variable.

Comment: check exactly what is being passed. the only difference between running it on sql server and through code is that you are assigning something to ur variables that causing the trouble

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. I was passing null value through parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the object names passed as parameter values that don't confirm to the rules for regular identifiers (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), need to be quoted.  USe the QUOTENAME function.  This will also mitigate the risk of SQL injection.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateCitationTrust]
@tblName varchar(50),
@updatedTableName varchar(50)

AS
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)
Declare @ParamDefinition AS NVarchar(2000) 
BEGIN
 --BEGIN TRANSACTION 


 set @sql='Update '+QUOTENAME(@updatedTableName)+ ' set [Citation Flow]=m2.[Citation Flow],'+
    ' [Trust Flow]=m2.[Trust Flow]'+
    ' FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@updatedTableName)+ ' m1 '+
    ' INNER JOIN  '+ QUOTENAME(@tblName)+' m2'+
    ' on m1.[Linking Domain]=m2.[Item]'

 Set @ParamDefinition =      '@tblName varchar(50),
                @updatedTableName varchar(50)'



 Execute sp_Executesql     @sql, 
                @ParamDefinition, 
                @tblName,
                @updatedTableName


    If @@ERROR <> 0 GoTo ErrorHandler 
    Set NoCount OFF
    Return(0)

ErrorHandler:
    Return(@@ERROR)
END
```